# HTML Video Video.js

Tags: html, html5-video

Hi Hope someone can help. 
Im Using HTML5 Video/Video.JS and cant seem to get the code to have the fallbacks of .ogv and .webm when I add the loop function ,{doLoop:true});

Also I have used the Miro converter and the .ovg video seems a low jumpy quality. has anyone got any suggestions on how to fix this?

This code works (no fall backs tho)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        var BV = new $.BigVideo();
        BV.init();
        BV.show('http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/feature-bank/media/featurebank.mp4',{doLoop:true});
    });
```

This code dose not work

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        var BV = new $.BigVideo();
        BV.init();
        BV.show('http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/featurebank/media/featurebank.mp4'{altSource:'http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/featurebank/media/featurebank.ogv',{doLoop:true});
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The options argument is mangled. Try this:

```
BV.show('http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/featurebank/media/featurebank.mp4',{altSource:'http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/featurebank/media/featurebank.ogv',doLoop:true});
```